# Are LaunchAgents supported by OS X 10.4?

Tags: launchd, osx-tiger

Are LaunchAgents supported by OS X 10.4?

I tested them on 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7, and it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) was introduced in Mac OS X 10.4 "Tiger", and so 10.4 does support LaunchAgents.

<sup>Whether that version supports the features you need is another question. It's not really possible to give a better answer without knowing more details about your particular problem.</sup>